# Trouble With Pasting Ranges When Not Stepping Through

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have 5 customer files I want to clean up with the below VBA code.  Everything works fine when I step through it. However; when I run the code, the wrong range is pasted in.  I've already spent some time in completely rewriting my range references to avoid using .Select anywhere.  It doesn't seem to have helped.  Any ideas?

```
Sub convert_Customer()

Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim wkbks As Workbooks
Dim wksht As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim Dir As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long

Application.CutCopyMode = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dir = "C:\Users\User\Documents\User\Customer\BI Input"

Excel.Workbooks.Open Dir & "\Customer.xlsx"
With Excel.Workbooks("Customer.xlsx").Sheets(1).Activate
    Set StartCell = Range("F15")
    LastRow = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    LastColumn = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    Set Rng = Range(StartCell, Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
    Rng.Select
    Rng.Copy
End With

Application.Workbooks.Add

Set wksht = Application.ActiveSheet

wksht.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

wksht.Range("A:A,C:G").NumberFormat = "@"
wksht.Range("B:B,H:CD").NumberFormat = "0.00"

Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Dir & "/Customer.csv", xlCSV

Excel.Workbooks("Customer.csv").Close
Excel.Workbooks("Customer.xlsx").Close

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: As soon as I finished reading the second sentence, I said to myself *must be a problem of unqualified ranges and relying on the ActiveSheet*.

Comment: I walked into this thinking "i bet he wants to activate, copy, paste all over the place."

Comment: Yup. I was thinking _if only VBA hadn't allowed unqualified object properties ... the SO question queue would be halved._